# Power series for non elementary functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, elementary-functions

Since the function $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ cannot be integrated using elementary functions, how could one find a power series for $F$, where $F$ is an elementary function such that $F'(x)=e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: What about a termwise integration of the power series of $e^{-x^2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{n!}$ ?

Comment: What  is proved is not only that one cannot compute such an $F$ in terms of elementary functions, it is that there exists *no* such expression.

Comment: If you have the Taylor series, you can integrate it term-wise.

Comment: What would I center the Taylor Series around though?

Answer (score 1):

Such an $F$ does not exists. There is no anti-derivative that is an elementary function.

Since $e^{-x^2}$ is an analytic function, you can still integrate the power series term by term to get an analytic anti-derivative, but this will not be an elementary function.

(Summarized from the comments.)